# AMD/ATI FirePro V5900 WebGl / OpenGl ES not supported?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, driver, ati, amd-processor

it seems that with the current (28. Feb. 2013) Catalyst driver from AMD ver. 9.3.3 WebGl is not supported. At least I'm not able to hook up Firefox or Chrome with native GL support. It only works with ANGLE enabled. So, is there a working driver available or what's the issue?

Further it seems that only Catalyst versions >10.8 support OpenGL ES but they have no support for FirePro according to release notes.

[release notes 10.8](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/Catalyst_108_release_notes.pdf)

[release notes 13.1](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalystSoftwareSuiteVersion131.aspx)

Comment: Is there a reason that ANGLE doesn't work for you? It generally works very well, and you're not necessarily going to get a performance boost by switching to native GL.

Comment: as i would expect a lot more performance this is not an issue anyway. the issue is with the statement limitation. my shader code is too big (for ANGLE) which is why i get an error during compiling.